# Terminal do not list JQ6500 chip (ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS) - But Okay with Ubuntu Mate (!?)

Tags: 16.04

The JQ6500 is a tiny hardware decoder providing serial MP3 chip.

MP3 USB transfert is native with Windows BUT there's a nice Linux port here: https://chiselapp.com/user/rmax/repository/jq6500/index

My problem is the JQ6500 is not recognized in the Terminal on my MacBookPro 2008 with ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS installed.

lsblk gives nothing about it.

However the JQ6500 is perfectly recognized on my RasberryPI3 with Ubuntu-Mate installed !

I'd like to have the chip working with ubuntu 16.04.2 and I don't understand why the OS does not identify it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of that Linux tool you found. :)

I also had issues with the module not being properly recognized by some machines, but working well on others (all running openSUSE). To me it looked like a hardware problem between the JQ6500 and some USB host controllers. Maybe the JQ6500's USB timing is at the edge of the specification and some host controller models (or even board designs) tolerate this better than others.

In my case it helped to put a USB hub between the problematic hosts and the JQ6500, but there it might as well depend on the hub (chip) model, whether  this helps or not.

You could also try out if there is a difference between different USB ports on the same machine.